# Are there any interesting examples of geometric triangulated categories with the Jordan-Holder property?

Tags: examples, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0903v1.pdf), Kuznetsov mentions that the following triangulated categories have the Jordan-Holder property

- $\mathbf{D}(\Bbb P^1)$ and $\mathbf{D}(\Bbb P^1/\Gamma)$
- connected Calabi-Yau categories
- derived categories of curves of positive genus

These are the only examples of geometric triangulated categories with the Jordan-Holder property that I know of. Are there any others?

Comment: One paper that comes to my mind containing related results is Hügel--Koenig--Liu, Jordan Hölder theorems for derived module categories of piecewise hereditary algebras. These examples are probably not geometric in your sense, but they are in Orlov's when considered as dg categories.